# how to convert sql union to linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, union

I have the following Transact SQL query using a union.
I need some pointers as to how this would look in LINQ i.e some examples
wouldbe nice or if anyone can recommend a good tutorial on UNIONS in linq.

```
select top 10 Barcode, sum(ItemDiscountUnion.AmountTaken) from
(SELECT d.Barcode,SUM(AmountTaken) AmountTaken
  FROM [Aggregation].[dbo].[DiscountPromotion] d

  GROUP BY d.Barcode

  UNION ALL

  SELECT i.Barcode,SUM(AmountTaken) AmountTaken
  FROM [Aggregation].[dbo].ItemSaleTransaction i

  group by i.Barcode)  ItemDiscountUnion

  group by Barcode
```

---

Note the original SQL is  *merging* the 2 selects NOT concatenating them.
I need to know how to merge the results i.e. removing duplicates and summing  the rows amount value where there is  duplication based on bar code.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386979.aspx

Comment: just use the Union operator as @Ian-P suggested

Answer (score 48):

Three useful Linq concepts operating on sets. Given set `c` and set `e`:

Concat gives you everything in `c` or `e`:

```
(From c In db.Customers Select c.Phone).Concat( _
             From c In db.Customers Select c.Fax).Concat( _
             From e In db.Employees Select e.HomePhone)

(From c In db.Customers _
            Select Name = c.CompanyName, Phone = c.Phone).Concat(From e In db.Employees _
            Select Name = e.FirstName & " " & e.LastName, Phone = e.HomePhone)
```

Union also gives you everything in `c` and `e`, but removes any duplicates:

```
(From c In db.Customers _
        Select c.Country).Union(From e In db.Employees _
        Select e.Country)
```

Except gives you everything in `c` that is not in `e`:

```
(From c In db.Customers _
             Select c.Country).Except(From e In db.Employees Select e.Country)
```

Comment: `Concat`, `Union` and `Except` are different things: `Concat` will just merge two sequences into one, `Union` will merge but remove duplicates (distinct), and `Except` is completely different: it returns the elements of the first sequence that do not belong to the second sequence. (the last one is `Intersect`: returns the common elements from 2 sequences)

Comment: As Guillaume86 mentioned, this post is incorrect.  A little wording change would easily fix the problem.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that like `Union`, `Except` and `Interset` also remove any duplicates, including duplicates in the source sequences.

Answer (score 13):

Here's an example of a generic union, without regard to the scenario you posted:

```
var something =
                (from e in _repository
                 select new { e.Property1, e.Property2 }).Union(
                (from e in _repository
                 select new { e.Property1, e.Property2 }));
```

Answer (score 5):

There are the [101 Linq Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) - with two union samples [Union1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#union1) and [Union2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#union2)

This Linq statement should get you the same results as your SQL:
(it has for me on a test record-set)

```
var results = (from a in (from d in DiscountPromotions
            group d by d.BarCode into g
            select new { 
                BarCode = g.Key,
                AmountTaken = g.Sum(p => p.AmountTaken)
                }).Union(from i in ItemSaleTransactions
            group i by i.BarCode into o
            select new { 
                BarCode = o.Key,
                AmountTaken = o.Sum(i => i.AmountTaken)
                }) group a by a.BarCode into b
                select new {
                    BarCode = b.Key,
                    AmountTaken = b.Sum(c => c.AmountTaken)
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return await (
                                 from b in _db.Brands
                                 where b.brand_id == 0
                                 select new brandInfo
                                 {
                                     brand_id = b.brand_id,
                                     brand_name = b.brand_name
                                 }).Union<brandInfo>(
                                        from pd in _db.Product_Details
                                        join b in _db.Brands on pd.brand_id equals b.brand_id
                                        where pd.cate_id == cate_id && pd.pro_id == pro_id || b.brand_id == 0
                                        select new brandInfo
                                        {
                                            brand_id = b.brand_id,
                                            brand_name = b.brand_name
                                        }
                              ).Distinct().OrderBy(o=>o.brand_name).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var discountPromotionQuery =
from d in dbContext.DiscountPromotion
group d by d.Barcode into g
select new
{
    Barcode = g.Key,
    AmountTaken = g.Sum(d => d.AmountTaken)
};

var itemSaleTransactionQuery =
from i in dbContext.ItemSaleTransaction
group i by i.Barcode into g
select new
{
    Barcode = g.Key,
    AmountTaken = g.Sum(i => i.AmountTaken)
};

var result =
(from d in discountPromotionQuery
 select new
 {
     d.Barcode,
     AmountTaken = d.AmountTaken
 })
.Concat(from i in itemSaleTransactionQuery
        select new
        {
            i.Barcode,
            AmountTaken = i.AmountTaken
        })
.GroupBy(x => x.Barcode)
.Select(g => new
{
    Barcode = g.Key,
    AmountTaken = g.Sum(x => x.AmountTaken)
})
.Take(10);
```