# Get data from both tables in LINQ

Tags: linq

I am trying to fetch an IP-address column which is present in both tables, *A* and *B*. Table *A* has many IP-adresses and a specific IP-address which is not present in table *B*. I want distinct IP-addresses from both the tables. That means I want all IP-adresses from table *A* which are not present in table *B*, plus all IP-adresses from table *B* which are not present in table *A*. I am trying the below code which is only giving me the IP-adresses which are not present in table *B*. Please help.

```
var ips= (from a in CS.A
 where !CS.B.Any(f => f.IPAddress == a.IPAddress)
    select a.IPAddress).Distinct();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert sql union to linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744205/how-to-convert-sql-union-to-linq)

Comment: just use the `.Union` operator (see the link I gave with the close-vote)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply  use this

```
 var ips= ((from a in CS.A
          where !CS.B.Any(f => f.IPAddress == a.IPAddress)
          select a.IPAddress).Distinct()).Union((from b in CS.B
          where !CS.A.Any(f => f.IPAddress == b.IPAddress)
          select b.IPAddress).Distinct());
```

Comment: @Carsten can you please explain

Answer (score 0):

You can just `Concat` both IP columns and `group by` the IPs.
Then only select the groups which have a count of 1 (= IP only occurs in one table)

```
var res =
        (from ip in CS.A.Select(x => x.ip)
                        .Distinct()
                        .Concat(CS.B.Select(x => x.ip).Distinct())
         group ip by ip into grp
         where grp.Count() == 1
         select grp.Key).ToList();
```

You can test this with the following example:

```
var x1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 20);       
var x2 = Enumerable.Range(5, 20);

var res =
        (from ip in x1.Select(x => x).Distinct().Concat(x2.Select(x => x).Distinct())
         group ip by ip into grp
         where grp.Count() == 1
         select grp.Key).ToList();

res.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score -1):

My first suggestion would be to use a store procedure to achieve that.  Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT tblA.ip, tblB.ip FROM Table1 tblA
INNER JOIN Table2 tblB
ON 1=1
GROUP BY tblA.ip
```

the "ON" here will give you a condition that is always true.

Roughly the same query should work with linq as well.  Experiment :-)

**edit**
UNION is also an option, however most not as easily read by non-SQL developers.

```
Select distinct cmnTbl.ip from (SELECT tblA.ip from Table1 tblA UNION SELECT tblB.ip from Table1) cmnTbl
```

Comment: @Carsten You are correct.  I usually prefer to use inner join and group by as it is more readable for the average Joe. But using Union and Distinct is a great "advanced" technique.

Comment: why would a simple `UNION` be harder to read than a `INNER JOIN` with a strange `ON 1=1`? - but do as you please - it just seemed really strange to me